# C# Service Develop and Install

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

I followed this guide to create a Webservice:
[Windows Service Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)
but haven't been able to install my service (code alone worked perfectly as a Windows App)

[image: InstallUtil Error]

Just what am i doing wrong?

English Error:
System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

Service Code:

```
namespace EmailDoc2
{
    public partial class Emailing : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer time = null;

        public Emailing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            time = new Timer();
            this.time.Interval = 43200000;
            this.time.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_tick);
            time.Enabled = true;
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("Log Boletas/logBoletas.txt"))
            EmailDoc.EmailDoc.Log("Service Started", w);
        }
        private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmailDoc.EmailDoc.Main();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            time.Enabled = false;
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("Log Boletas/logBoletas.txt"))
            EmailDoc.EmailDoc.Log("Service Stopped", w);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the text of the error message translated into English?

Comment: Added translation

Comment: You may also want to check out the TopShelf library that makes Windows service development easy and more powerful https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a rookie mistake, but finally, the page was not wrong at all, the problem i faced was that i erased part of the code that starts the windows service:

```
namespace EnvioDocumentos
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Code bellow is default, never erase
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new EnvioDocs() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
       }
    }
}
```

For newbies like me, i'd highly recommend creating a new class (Library.cs) where you call your methods, this way you won't get stuck with the "i have no idea how this service thing works"

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = yourtime;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timertick); //<== This function starts every "yourtime" in milliseconds
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Test start"); //<== best practice ever to write a log every beginning
        }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#BK_CreateProject